# Analize camera data with AndAR without showing on screen

Tags: android, artoolkit, andar

I'm using a code that uses camera data about an AR marker to calculate the Android device position using AndAR (based on ARToolkit).

The point is that I want to make that analyze while I'm printing an other 3D object render, ho has noting  in common with the camera and the AR tag.

Someone has an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to my own question, it's not possible to analyze the images within outputing them, because the main activity used by the ARToolkit inherits from AndARActivity, that inherits from activity, so they need a layout.

The solution that I'm using is:

-I implement 2 apps, the first one take images from the camera and make the necessary analyse and the second one use the data from the first one

-I implement a osc transmission for sharing data between apps

-I force the first app to keep runing, soo it keep getting the camera data while the second starts

I think it's not the best option, but I need results and that way it works.